# CAST ERROR IN R Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , variables, drop = FALSE) : undefined columns selected

Tags: r, casting

I am getting this error in R when casting data using package "Reshape":

```
"Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , variables, drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected"
```

Waterquality Data look like this:

```
   year turbid.ave.mo month2
16 2002     926.66667   JUNE
23 2002     493.66667   JULY
29 2002     107.10000    AUG
37 2002     295.80000   SEPT
46 2002     528.28000    OCT
53 2002     266.20000    NOV
56 2002      73.80000    DEC
1  2003     115.00000    JAN
```

I want to cast so that month is column header (one row per year with JAN to DEC as column headers.

Code I tried:

```
casted = cast(Waterquality [ ,c(1:3)], year + turbid.ave.mo ~ month2, mean, fill =0, value = "turbid.ave.mo")
```

Error: Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , variables, drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected

Anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?  Thanks in advance!!

Comment: For future questions please remember that in the R tag we require you to use `dput()` to share your data.

Comment: `cast` is not an R function. Consider giving enough info in your question so that others can run your code.

Comment: thanks, had this problem too. seem incorrectly explained on https://www.r-statistics.com/tag/transpose/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a much cleaner `tidyr` solution:

```
library(tidyr)

spread(Waterquality, month2, turbid.ave.mo, fill = 0)
# year        Apr      Aug       Feb        Jan         Jul      Jun        Mar       May
# 1 2002 -0.2798722 0.000000 -0.901421 -0.9576323 -0.07627388 0.652116 -0.3758433 0.9795479
# 2 2003  0.0000000 1.047832  0.000000  0.0000000  0.00000000 0.000000  0.0000000 0.0000000
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't include the value in the formula:

```
cast(Waterquality [ ,c(1:3)], year ~ month2, mean, fill =0, value = "turbid.ave.mo")

  year   AUG  DEC JAN     JULY     JUNE   NOV    OCT  SEPT
1 2002 107.1 73.8   0 493.6667 926.6667 266.2 528.28 295.8
2 2003   0.0  0.0 115   0.0000   0.0000   0.0   0.00   0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Initially had the data as :(Id,Value,Variable) 
Just re-arranged the order to (Id,Variable,Value).

```
    cast (tmp, id ~ delivery_month)
```